# Mysql: difference between intvalue='1' and intvalue=1

Tags: mysql, integer, equals

On an `int` column, is there difference between doing..

`SELECT .. int = '1'` and `SELECT .. int = 1`, and which would be preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `int = 1`, because `int = '1'` is internally converted to `int = cast('1' as int)`

Answer (score 1):

Not a MySql expert, but I would say that the first one (`int = '1'`) would cause a conversion of the string to an integer before comparison.

So to avoid this conversion, I would always go with the right data type.

Additionally, a conversion is not guaranteed to succeed (or give the correct results).

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that if your query has a var that can be empty you'll get this

```
SELECT .... int = ''
```

versus

```
SELECT .... int =
```

And the last one is invalid SQL. The first one will give you all empty values (maybe nothing if there are none ofcourse). although I agree if one says it should be caught before the query, it is a difference that can byte you :)

Answer (score 0):

The first one (int = '1') compares a string to an integer (so mysql automaticly converts this)
The seconds one (int = 1) compares an integer to an integer field (no conversion needed).

So the second one is preferred